# Simple binary tree question

Tags: java, binary-tree

I was wanting to display all of the nodes at a certain level in the tree:

Called by: `allNodesAtACertainLevel(0, *whatever level you want*, root);`

This produces the correct answer.

```
private void allNodesAtACertainLevel(int count, int level, Node n){

        count += 1;

        if(count <= level){
            if(n.left != null) allNodesAtACertainLevel(count, level, n.left);
            if(n.right != null) allNodesAtACertainLevel(count, level, n.right);
        }
        else{
            System.out.print(n.value);
        }

    }
```

This doesn't.

```
private void allNodesAtACertainLevel(int count, int level, Node n){

        if(count < level){
            if(n.left != null) allNodesAtACertainLevel(count++, level, n.left);
            if(n.right != null) allNodesAtACertainLevel(count++, level, n.right);
        }
        else{
            System.out.print(n.value);
        }

    }
```

Could someone explain why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second example increments `count` twice, the first example increments `count` only once. Also the first increments `count` before calls to `allNodesAtACertainLevel` while second example calls `allNodesAtACertainLevel` and increments `count` *after* the call.

Any of these should produce a correct result when substituted appropriately for the second example:

```
count++;
if(n.left != null) allNodesAtACertainLevel(count, level, n.left);
if(n.right != null) allNodesAtACertainLevel(count, level, n.right);
```

--

```
count += 1;
if(n.left != null) allNodesAtACertainLevel(count, level, n.left);
if(n.right != null) allNodesAtACertainLevel(count, level, n.right);
```

--

```
if(n.left != null) allNodesAtACertainLevel(count+1, level, n.left);
if(n.right != null) allNodesAtACertainLevel(count+1, level, n.right);
```

Comment: I thought it would only increment the value within the scope of the respective recursive call.

Comment: @Ryan: It increments it within the scope of the variable, not in the call. I've added some equivalent versions, the last is likely what you were really going for.

Comment: You're correct, the last example is what I thought would be happening. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is because you are making count++ to times, so you increment the level counter one extra time.

You should change your code to the following:

```
count++;
if(n.left != null) allNodesAtACertainLevel(count, level, n.left);
if(n.right != null) allNodesAtACertainLevel(count, level, n.right);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return an incorrect answer if the left node were ever null and the right node wasn't?

Comment: You are right, i have missed the one-liner if statement, corrected now.